# Sanity Check: best ffmpeg options for YT with Logitech C920 & Pi 4B

Tags: video, ffmpeg, youtube, video-streaming, command-line-arguments

I have a Raspberry Pi 4 Model B and a Logitech C920 camera attached, streaming to YouTube over 500Mbps connection. It's working okay for the most part, but I'm not sure if I'm being dumb with my ffmpeg options, or if the camera is underpowered, or what. A lot of my options are total shots in the dark and/or educated guesses, e.g. my thread count values. Do things generally look correct?

Small annoyance:

- using a pixel format of MJPEG gets me ~22fps, but yuv420p or yuyv422 only gets me 10fps.
- if I set exposure_auto_priority to 1 and exposure_auto to 1, it drops to 10fps as well.

Here's the output of v4l2-ctl --all:

```
Driver Info:
    Driver name      : uvcvideo
    Card type        : HD Pro Webcam C920
    Bus info         : usb-0000:01:00.0-1.2
    Driver version   : 5.10.60
    Capabilities     : 0x84a00001
        Video Capture
        Metadata Capture
        Streaming
        Extended Pix Format
        Device Capabilities
    Device Caps      : 0x04200001
        Video Capture
        Streaming
        Extended Pix Format
Media Driver Info:
    Driver name      : uvcvideo
    Model            : HD Pro Webcam C920
    Serial           : 1E2FBA1F
    Bus info         : usb-0000:01:00.0-1.2
    Media version    : 5.10.60
    Hardware revision: 0x00000019 (25)
    Driver version   : 5.10.60
Interface Info:
    ID               : 0x03000002
    Type             : V4L Video
Entity Info:
    ID               : 0x00000001 (1)
    Name             : HD Pro Webcam C920
    Function         : V4L2 I/O
    Flags         : default
    Pad 0x01000007   : 0: Sink
      Link 0x0200001f: from remote pad 0x100000a of entity 'Processing 3': Data, Enabled, Immutable
Priority: 2
Video input : 0 (Camera 1: ok)
Format Video Capture:
    Width/Height      : 1280/720
    Pixel Format      : 'MJPG' (Motion-JPEG)
    Field             : None
    Bytes per Line    : 0
    Size Image        : 1843200
    Colorspace        : sRGB
    Transfer Function : Rec. 709
    YCbCr/HSV Encoding: ITU-R 601
    Quantization      : Default (maps to Full Range)
    Flags             :
Crop Capability Video Capture:
    Bounds      : Left 0, Top 0, Width 1280, Height 720
    Default     : Left 0, Top 0, Width 1280, Height 720
    Pixel Aspect: 1/1
Selection: crop_default, Left 0, Top 0, Width 1280, Height 720, Flags:
Selection: crop_bounds, Left 0, Top 0, Width 1280, Height 720, Flags:
Streaming Parameters Video Capture:
    Capabilities     : timeperframe
    Frames per second: 24.000 (24/1)
    Read buffers     : 0
                     brightness 0x00980900 (int)    : min=0 max=255 step=1 default=128 value=170
                       contrast 0x00980901 (int)    : min=0 max=255 step=1 default=128 value=128
                     saturation 0x00980902 (int)    : min=0 max=255 step=1 default=128 value=212
 white_balance_temperature_auto 0x0098090c (bool)   : default=1 value=1
                           gain 0x00980913 (int)    : min=0 max=255 step=1 default=0 value=255
           power_line_frequency 0x00980918 (menu)   : min=0 max=2 default=2 value=0
      white_balance_temperature 0x0098091a (int)    : min=2000 max=6500 step=1 default=4000 value=3055 flags=inactive
                      sharpness 0x0098091b (int)    : min=0 max=255 step=1 default=128 value=223
         backlight_compensation 0x0098091c (int)    : min=0 max=1 step=1 default=0 value=0
                  exposure_auto 0x009a0901 (menu)   : min=0 max=3 default=3 value=3
              exposure_absolute 0x009a0902 (int)    : min=3 max=2047 step=1 default=250 value=416 flags=inactive
         exposure_auto_priority 0x009a0903 (bool)   : default=0 value=0
                   pan_absolute 0x009a0908 (int)    : min=-36000 max=36000 step=3600 default=0 value=0
                  tilt_absolute 0x009a0909 (int)    : min=-36000 max=36000 step=3600 default=0 value=-10800
                 focus_absolute 0x009a090a (int)    : min=0 max=250 step=5 default=0 value=0
                     focus_auto 0x009a090c (bool)   : default=1 value=0
                  zoom_absolute 0x009a090d (int)    : min=100 max=500 step=1 default=100 value=130
```

Here's the full ffmpeg command line I'm using:

```
ffmpeg -hide_banner -loglevel repeat+level+info -nostdin -fflags +nobuffer \
    -f v4l2 \
    -thread_queue_size 24000000 \
    -pix_fmt mjpeg \
    -video_size 1280x720 \
    -framerate 24 \
    -i /dev/video0 \
    -f alsa \
    -thread_queue_size 24000000 \
    -channel_layout stereo \
    -ar 32000 \
    -i hw:CARD=C920,DEV=0 \
    -f flv \
    -flvflags no_duration_filesize \
    -preset ultrafast \
    -crf 30 \
    -video_size 1280x720 \
    -threads 16 \
    -framerate 24 \
    -c:v libx264 \
    -x264opts cabac=1:lookahead-threads=20:sliced-threads:keyint=60:scenecut=0 \
    -tune zerolatency \
    -pixel_format mjpeg \
    -bf 2 \
    -c:a aac \
    -b:a 160k \
    -ac 2 \
    -ar 32000 \
    -filter_script:v /tmp/ffmpeg-filter.txt \
    -fflags +flush_packets \
    rtmp://a.rtmp.youtube.com/live2/*my_private_key*
```

Does anything there look stupidly amiss?

Comment: "MJPEG gets me ~22fps, but yuv420p or yuyv422 only gets me 10fps" - This one I know the answer. `mjpeg` is compressed while the others aren't, so transferring raw video over USB takes a lot longer than `mjpeg` video.

Comment: If `exposure_auto` is a camera setting (like turning on/off auto exposure adjustment algorithm) then the frame rate could also drop because camera is busy adjusting its exposure level rather than pumping out frames.

Comment: Thanks @kesh, that certainly makes sense. I must be assuming the C920 has more pep than it actually does. (It's only USB 2 after all, and a budget cam as well.)